# node.js Osmosis get resulsts after compiling js

Tags: node.js, osmosis

im trying to get data from site with osmosis, but insted of the value it returns '{{value}}'. 
here`s my code:

```html
const osmosis = require('osmosis');
osmosis
    .get('#########&fromStationCode=210305&toStationCode=217304')
    .delay(3000)
    .find('td').set('Result')`
    .data(console.log)
```

at this page values inserted into table via js. i tried to use delay but it didn`t work

Comment: also the info i`m looking for is pronted in consol.log on this site, is there a way to grab it from there?

Answer (score 0):

instead osmosis i`ve tried nightmare.js and it works for me